# Angularjs with nested directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, nested, directive

Index.html:

```
<nav-wrapper title="Email Test">
    <nav-elem value="first"></nav-elem>
    <nav-elem value="second"></nav-elem>
</nav-wrapper>
```

app.js:

```
app.directive('navWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@"
        },
        template: '<div class="wrapper"><p class="title">{{::title}}</p><ul>'
    }
});


app.directive('navElem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            value: "@?"
        },
        template: '<li class="navElem">{{::value}}</li>'
    }
});
```

output:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="title">Email Test</p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

desired output:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="title">Email Test</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="navElem">first</li>
        <li class="navElem">second</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Currently all tags in directive navWrapper are closed before the navElems are shown. Is there a way to tell 'navWrapper' including all child elements before the closing 'ul div' to reach the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transclude:true` in your `nav-wrapper` directive.

```
app.directive('navWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@"
        },
        template: '<div class="wrapper"><p class="title">{{::title}}</p><ul ng-transclude></ul></div>'
    }
});
```

Check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMYapviwNhvho1QiVlQ5?p=preview)